# Syntax error (operator missing) in query-expression?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to understand COUNT(*), and therefore I created a testing query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 WHERE COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30;
```

When I click Execute, I get the following error:

> Syntax error (operator missing) in query-expression COUNT(*) WHERE COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the table name?

Comment: The table name is UITLENINGEN, I put it in between the COUNT brackets.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UITLENINGEN
 WHERE COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UITLENINGEN GROUP BY LLNR HAVING COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30;
```

Comment: I get the following error (translated from Dutch):

You cannot use a statistic function in a WHERE-component (COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30).

Should I perhaps try HAVING?

Comment: select count(*) 
from UITLENINGEN
having count(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30;

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to do.  The query below is based on a table which includes a field named `category_id`.  And it uses `GROUP BY category_id` to count the number of rows within each such group. The `HAVING` clause limits the result set to only those groups whose count is at least 30.

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY category_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30;
```

If that is nothing like what you're trying to accomplish, please give us more detailed information so we may better understand your situation.  A brief set of sample data, and the output you want based on that sample, would help tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the table from which the data should be retrieved. Try the following

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) from tableName
    WHERE COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your table name to the query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UITLENINGEN WHERE COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30;
```

Comment: I get the following error (translated from Dutch):

You cannot use a statistic function in a WHERE-component (COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30).

Should I perhaps try HAVING?

Comment: @Tanno what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please, add table name and use `having` statement where aggregation funcion required. E.g.:

```
select count(*) 
from UITLENINGEN
having count(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) >= 30;
```